# The received message does not appear until the page is reloaded MERN & socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, chat, real-time

i made a chat page in my website with MERN & socket.io and while am testing it the received message does not shown until i reload the page ... i checked my codes over and over but i dont know where the mistake that i did it

this is my socket io server code:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8800, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    }
})

let activeUsers = []

io.on("connection", (socket)=> {

    // add new user
    socket.on('new-user-add', (newUserId)=> {
        // if user is added previously
        if(!activeUsers.some((user)=> user.userId === newUserId))
        {
            activeUsers.push({
                userId: newUserId,
                socketId: socket.id
            })
        }
        io.emit('get-users', activeUsers)
        console.log("Connected Users", activeUsers)
    })

    // send message
    socket.on("send-message", (data)=>{
        const {receiverId} = data;
        const user = activeUsers.find((user)=> user.userId === receiverId)
        console.log("sending from socket to : ", receiverId)
        console.log("Data: ", data)
        if(user){
            io.to(user.socketId).emit("receive-message", data)
        }
    })

    socket.on("disconnect", ()=> {
        activeUsers = activeUsers.filter((user)=> user.socketId !== socket.id)
        console.log("User Disconnected", activeUsers)
        io.emit('get-users', activeUsers)
    })

})
```

this is my Chat.jsx component code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Chat.css';
import LogoSearch from "../../components/logoSearch/LogoSearch"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { userChats } from '../../api/ChatRequests';
import Conversation from '../../components/conversation/Conversation';
import { UilSetting } from "@iconscout/react-unicons";
import Home from "../../img/home.png";
import Noti from "../../img/noti.png";
import Comment from "../../img/comment.png";
import ChatBox from '../../components/chatBox/ChatBox';
import {io} from "socket.io-client";

const Chat = () => {

  const {user} = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.authData);
  console.log(user)

  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);
  const [currentChat, setCurrentChat] = useState(null);
  const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState([]);
  const [sendMessage, setSendMessage] = useState(null);
  const [recieveMessage, setRecieveMessage] = useState(null);

  const socket = useRef()


  // sending message to socket server
  useEffect(()=> {
    if(sendMessage !== null){
      socket.current.emit('send-message', sendMessage)
    }
  },[sendMessage])
  
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    socket.current = io('http://localhost:8800');
    socket.current.emit("new-user-add", user._id)
    socket.current.on('get-users', (users)=>{
      setOnlineUsers(users);
    })
  },[user])

  // receive message from socket server
  useEffect(()=> {
    socket.current.on("receive-message", (data)=> {
      console.log("Data Received in parent Chat.jsx",data)
      setRecieveMessage(data)
    })
  },[])

  useEffect(()=> {
    const getChats = async()=> {
      try {
        const {data} = await userChats(user._id)
        setChats(data);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        
      }
    };
    getChats();
  },[user])
  return (
    <div className='Chat'>
      {/* Left Side */}
      <div className="Left-side-chat">
        <LogoSearch/>
        <div className="Chat-container">

        <h2>Chats</h2>
        <div className="Chat-list">
          {chats.map((chat)=> (
            <div onClick={()=>setCurrentChat(chat)}>
              <Conversation data={chat} currentUserId = {user._id}/>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Right Side */}
      <div className="Right-side-chat">
        <div style={{width:'20rem', alignSelf:'flex-end'}}>
        <div className="navIcons">
            <Link to='../home'>
                <img src={Home} alt="" />
            </Link>
            <UilSetting/>
            <img src={Noti} alt="" />
            <Link to='../chat'>
            <img src={Comment} alt="" />
            </Link>
        </div>

        {/* chat body */}
        <ChatBox 
        chat={currentChat} 
        currentUser={user._id} 
        setSendMessage={setSendMessage}
        recieveMessage={recieveMessage}
        />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chat
```

this is my ChatBox.jsx component code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { getUser } from '../../api/UserRequest';
import { addMessage, getMessages } from '../../api/MessageRequest';
import "./ChatBox.css";
import {format} from "timeago.js";
import InputEmoji from "react-input-emoji";

const ChatBox = ({chat, currentUser, setSendMessage, recieveMessage}) => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState("");
    const scroll = useRef()

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(recieveMessage !== null && recieveMessage?.chatId === chat?._id){
            setMessages([...messages, recieveMessage]);
        }
    }, [recieveMessage]);

    // fetching data for header
    useEffect(()=>{
        const userId = chat?.members?.find((id)=> id !== currentUser)

        const getUserData = async()=> {
            try {
                const {data} = await getUser(userId)
            setUserData(data)
            console.log(data)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            
        }
        if(chat !== null) getUserData();
    }, [chat, currentUser])

    // fetching data for messages
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchMessages = async ()=> {
            try {
                const {data} = await getMessages(chat._id)
                console.log(data)
                setMessages(data)
            } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            }
        }
        if(chat !== null) fetchMessages()
    },[chat]);

    const handleChange = (newMessage) => {
        setNewMessage(newMessage)
    }

    const handleSend = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const message = {
            senderId:currentUser,
            text: newMessage,
            chatId: chat._id,
        }

        // send message to database
        try {
            const { data } = await addMessage(message);
            setMessages([...messages, data])
            setNewMessage("")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            
        }

        // send message to socket server
        const receiverId = chat.members.find((id)=> id !== currentUser);
        setSendMessage([...message, receiverId])
    }

    // Always scroll to last message
    useEffect(()=>{
        scroll.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
    },[messages])

  return (
    <>
    <div className="ChatBox-container">
        {chat?(<>
        <div className="chat-header">
            <div className="follower">
            <div>
            <img src={
                userData?.profilePicture
                ? process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER + userData.profilePicture 
                : process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER + 'user.jpg'} alt="" 
                className='followerImage'
                style={{width: '50px', height: '50px', borderRadius:'50%'}}
                />
                <div className="name" style={{fontSize:'0.8rem'}}>
                    <span>{userData?.name}</span>
                    <small>@{userData?.username}</small>
                </div>
        </div>
            </div>
            <hr style={{width:'85%', border:'0.1px solid #ececec'}}/>
        </div>
        {/* chatbox Messages */}
        <div className="chat-body">
            {messages.map((message)=>(
                <>
                <div ref={scroll}
                className={message.senderId === currentUser? "message own": "message"}>
                    <span>{message.text}</span>
                    <span>{format(message.createdAt)}</span>
                </div>
                </>
            ))}
        </div>
        {/* chat-sender */}
        <div className="chat-sender">
            <div>+</div>
            <InputEmoji
            value={newMessage}
            onChange={handleChange}/>
            <div className="send-button button" onClick={handleSend}>Send</div>
        </div>
        </>
        ) : (
        <span className='chatbox-empty-message'>
            Tap on a Chat to start Conversation...
        </span>
            )}
        
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ChatBox
```